# What is the difference between といったところです and というところです?

Tags: grammar

> 銀行に変化を促しているのがタイの中央銀行です。 日本で言えば、日銀が腰を上げて、変革の旗振り役をしている**といったところです**。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/business_tokushu/2018_0820.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_001))

Could we replace といったところです by というところです here? If yes, what would be the difference? If not, why?

Comment: No, you can't as it (変化を促す）is already happening or happened. というところ if not yet.

Comment: I don't think the time-related reference of 変化を促している has any bearing on the choice between といった and という.

Comment: This is a difficult question. というところ is ok, if not the best, but still といったところ feels better.

Answer (score 0):

According to the dictionary といった is used to present examples.
といった【と言った】例示する意を表す。…のような。…などの。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154790/meaning/m0u/といった/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154790/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F/)
Example:
テニスや卓球と言ったスポーツ。
Sports like tennis or ping-pong.

という is used to present an explanation.
という【と言う】人が…と呼ぶ。…と呼ばれる。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/と言う/#je-52678](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86/#je-52678)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154743/meaning/m1u/という/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154743/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86/)
Examples:
ジョンという男の子
a boy named John
銀座という繁華街
a shopping area called “the Ginza”

ところ can also mean an abstract place, a position, a situation, a status.
事柄。内容。こと。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/158611/meaning/m0u/ところ/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/158611/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D/)

So the translation becomes:
変革の旗振り役をしているといったところです。
A situation similar to a person waving a revolutionary flag.

But if you use という:
変革の旗振り役をしているというところです。
A place called "a person waving a revolutionary flag"
which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Both could be used but というところです　sounds more direct than といったところです.This is like the difference between indicative and subjunctive. In English you can say "He speaks like a hero." and "He speaks as if he were a hero." The former is direct and the latter is not so direct since the tense is subjunctive.